# Mysql query compare string (varchar) as integer

Tags: php, mysql, comparison, type-conversion

I am not sure if there is a function within mysql query. I have a price table, and the column name is "price" and its type is VARCHAR(). I intentionally needed it as VARCHAR for many reason.

Now the problem is if I want to search products for maximum price of e.g. 100000, but in my column we have different types of prices, example below:-

1. TBD 374,500
2. Negotiation
3. 299,000

I am looking for a function like intVal() which will first convert the field value itself to INTEGER and compare it. Below is my current statement in query:-

... AND price <= $maximum_price

may be something like this should be the solution : intVal(price) <= $maximum_price

any help or direction towards solutions is appreciated. cheers

Comment: Cleanse the prices in your database and store as a numeric datatype, with a separate flag column to identify "Negotiable", etc

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

String values are "0". other values are sorted..

```
SELECT CAST(price AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) price 
FROM tt order by price desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in PHP there is no function like that. You have to hard code it yourself for getting a suitable result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(price, ',', ''), ' ', -1) AS SIGNED) <= $maximum_price
```

But I agree with previous comment, you'd better to rethink your table.

Answer (score 0):

look like you have various formats in the price column. I think you are looking to compare if  value in column is "TBD 374,500" then compare 374500 to 100000

In this case simple integer casting will convert all prices started with char to 0. you have to create your own function in mysql to take care of all formats.